# MySQL Find an ID based on 2 ids

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

i would like to see if player A (9) and player B (14) have ever both entered the same round, one round has many entries by many players. this is the middle table of a many to many relationship between rounds and players

```
table: entries
id | roundID | PlayerID   
5  | 7       | 14
4  | 6       | 2
3  | 5       | 14
2  | 5       | 9
1  | 4       | 9
```

Im looking to return round ID 5 obviously, but what SQL statement does this need? a JOIN?

i could do it by getting all rounds played by player A and B seperately looping through As rounds and looping through Bs rounds on each iteration of A to look for a match, but that seems needlessly costly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work, basically getting a count of all the PlayerID enteries per roundID for only the specified players and restricting to show only ones with multiples.

```
SELECT
    roundID
FROM
    entries
WHERE
    PlayerID IN (9, 14)
GROUP BY
    roundID
HAVING
    COUNT(*)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, something as simple as a `SELECT DISTINCT` will work here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT roundID
FROM entries
WHERE PlayerID IN (9, 14)
```

Comment: Won't this return `7,5,4` and not just `5`? I think the OP wants the `roundID` where both `PlayerID` exist.

Answer (score 0):

Use INNER JOIN with subqueries as follow

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tests WHERE `player_id`='9') t9 INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tests WHERE `player_id`='14') t14 ON `t9`.`round_id` = `t14`.`round_id`